# How to send an email from .aspx page?

Tags: asp.net

I used text boxes and a submit button on my .aspx page and I want to email the data of all these text boxes on Button click, so please tell me the solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on the button click event call this function

```
public bool SendOnlyToEmail(string sToMailAddr, string sSubject, string sMessage,
                                         string sFromMailAddr)
            {
                try
                {
                    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sFromMailAddr))
                    {
// fetching from address from web config key
                        msg.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailFrom"]); 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        msg.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(sFromMailAddr);
                    }

                    foreach (string address in sToMailAddr)
                    {
                        if (address.Length > 0)
                        {
                            msg.To.Add(address);
                        }
                    }
                    msg.Subject = sSubject;
                    msg.Body = sMessage;
                    msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

                    //fetching smtp address from web config key
                    System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient objSMTPClient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailServer"]);
                    //SmtpMail.SmtpServer = Convert.ToString(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailServer"]);
                    if (sToMailAddr.Length > 0)
                    {
                        objSMTPClient.Send(msg);
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception objException)
                {
                    ErrorLog.InsertException(objException);
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`SmtpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) class.

Answer (score 2):

There's no code-only way to solve this; you're dependent on having an SMTP server to dispatch your mail.  Best case scenario: you already have one set up on your server with the default port.  In that case, all you need is this:

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("localhost");
client.Send(new MailMessage("me@myserver.com", "someoneelse@foo.com"));
```

Failing that, you could look into setting up a free SMTP account, or (absolutely necessary anyway if you're planning on sending out bulk emails), getting an account with an email service provider like Amazon SES.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code to send the email:

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("senderEmail");
message.From = fromAddress;
message.Subject = "your subject";
message.Body = txtBox.Text;//Here put the textbox text
message.To.Add("to");
smtpClient.Send(message);//returns the boolean value ie. success:true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <script runat="server">

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //create the mail message
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

            //set the addresses
            mail.From = new MailAddress("info@infoA2Z.com");
            mail.To.Add("Support@infoA2Z.com");

            //set the content
            mail.Subject = "This is an email";
            mail.Body = "this is the body content of the email.";

            //send the message
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Send(mail);
        }
    </script>
```